# spring-amqp one queue multiple listeners

Tags: java, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

How can I configure the receiver for following requirement

I have three tasks which will listen all the replies on single queue "replyQueue"

```
task1 
task2
task3
```

Each one is going to send one message on `Rabbit` and will wait for the response on the `replyQueue`

Task1

```
     -send message 
        -wait for the responses 
        -There can be multiple responses 
                -status message 1
                -status message 2
                -final message
```

task2

```
-send message 
    -wait for the responses 
    -There can be multiple responses 
            -status message 1
            -status message 2
            -final message
```

task3

```
-send message 
    -wait for the responses 
    -There can be multiple responses 
            -status message 1
            -status message 2
            -final message
```

Now I have to do different tasks depending upon the response.
How i can configure my queues and listeners?

I tried with following

```
template.send("TaskQueue",message);
Message response= template.receive("replyQueue");
```

but this will allow me to read only one response but i want to read multiple response for each task1

Please guide .

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something in your question, you can simply do multiple `receive()` calls.

You can't use the same reply queue if these tasks run concurrently - otherwise the tasks will get each other's replies - in that case you need a different reply queue for each.

Comment: There will be only one task running at a time but using only one replyQueue is my requirement.

Comment: So why can't you just execute multiple `receive()` s ?

Comment: Earlier I was thinking to use MessageListener and the method onMessage()
But yes I have added multiple receive() and it is working fine for me.

thanks